# Highlight a word in a picturebox that contains a scanned image

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have a program that displays a scanned bitmap image to an operator and allows them to enter information from the scanned image. The image has been run through OCR so I know where each word is on the page with x,y,w,h coordinates in pixels.

What I would like to do it have the program highlight the word based on the coordinates captured. I want to help the operator to see the area where the OCR value came from. This will help them easily determine if the OCR is correct.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to highlight an area of the picturebox based on the coordinates I have.

The image in the picturebox is inside a SplitContainer and displayed fit-to-width and resizes as the form or split panel changes size.

Any ideas how to do this?
[image: Example Interface Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could draw a translucent rectangle at the co-ordinates of the word. The height would be the line height, and the width would be calculated using character width of the scanned font * the word length.

Comment: I tried doing this on the picturebox and get the error "A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format" -- I assume that is because the image is black & white. I need to keep the image load times fast so I would rather not convert to rgb if possible. Any idea how to draw a rectangle on this? (I have the exact locations of words in pixels from the ocr sdk)

Comment: Draw over the picture box, not into it.

Comment: I had the same thought, but for the life of me I can't figure out to draw on top of a picturebox, or any other control. I can draw on the form, but it paints behind the controls, not on top. If you know how that can be done I'd buy you a beer for letting me in on the secret.